# How to fix System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated in table '

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq

I'm coming in here very upset. My app started throwing me this exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated in table 'SmartOne.dbo.Problem', column 'nameOfAlert'. Truncated value: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and l'.

I know that this exception is thrown if I store a colunm larger than the given one. But I find it strange that nothing like that is possible. The data is still sent the same size, the emails themselves are also sent the same size (For the test, the application extracts the data from the email). Until last night it worked normally.

This morning I was sending a demo to a colleague and suddenly this problem occurred.
Does anyone know what's wrong? I'm really worried because nobody touched the application code and yet this exception is thrown

> Method for saving data to DB, there the exception is throwed

```cs
public void Save(Problem element)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseSingleton.connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Problem VALUES " +
            "(@nameOfAlert , @value , @result , @message_ID) ", conn))
        {

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nameOfAlert", element.NameOfAlert));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", (int)element.Value));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@result", (int)element.Result));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@message_ID", element.Message_Id));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Exception is throwed there
            command.CommandText = "Select @@Identity";
            element.Id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        
        
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

> Where Save method I am using

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
{
    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
    GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
    Problem problem = new Problem(message.MessageId);
    if (!dAOProblem.GetAll().Any(x => x.Message_Id.Equals(problem.Message_Id)))
    {
        dAOProblem.Save(problem);
        Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1, problem.Id);
        if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(alert.Id_MimeMessage)))
        {
            dAOAlert.Save(alert);
            LoadAlertGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
        }

    }
}
```

> Here I am saving new Alerts

```
 public void Save(Alert element)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseSingleton.connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Alert] VALUES (@message_ID, @date, @email, @AMUser_ID, @Problem_ID) ", conn))
                    {

                 
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@message_ID", element.Id_MimeMessage));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", element.Date));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", element.Email));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AMUser_ID", element.User_ID));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Problem_ID", element.Problem_ID));

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.CommandText = "Select @@Identity";
                        element.Id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                    
                
                    }
               
                conn.Close();
            }
           
           
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:
Now I am having Issue to save Alerts. With FK of Problem specially...**

Comment: Out of curiosity, did the column size on the DB did change ?! To a Debug, check the length of the `element.NameOfAlert`
That error only happens when you are trying to put more characters into the column that it can handle

Comment: @Camadas I checked this out and new exception appearead. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@nameOfAlert nvarchar(4000),@value int,@result int,@message_ID ' expects the parameter '@nameOfAlert', which was not supplied.' `  nameOfAlert is obtained from the text of the email. I read email `TextBody` in new app and `TextBody`  is not empty.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the correct data types and sizes for your parameters (as defined by the table schema in the database)? e.g.: `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nameOfAlert", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000)).Value = element.NameOfAlert;`

Comment: For the newest exception, have you tried clearing the command's parameter collection before invoking `command.ExecuteScalar()`? The second statement isn't expecting any parameters.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for your great advices. I totally don't understand why I am getting this kind of issues, yesterday it worked, uh. I have new one.  I deleted all columns, now I cannot save them.  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Alert__Problem_I__17F790F9". The conflict occurred in database "SmartOne", table "dbo.Problem", column 'id'. The statement has been terminated.'`

Comment: I also added UPDATE in my question

Comment: FK constraint error means that the key, from what I'm seeing from you code is the one in the property `Problem_ID` in `Alert` doesn't exist on your table `dbo.Problem`

Comment: But the Problem_ID existst... in table :D

Comment: It works if I am inserting new row into in MS studio

Comment: Using the same connection string ? If yes thats strange, that FK error occurs in this type of situations.
Just for debug sake, to a `select * from dbo.Problem where id = *Problem_ID*`

Comment: I can see it now, If I am debbuging `Problem_ID` value is alwayse 0

Comment: Id is set to `Identity`, so I am not inserting the Id

Comment: @Camadas Maybe I should create new question, in this case

Comment: If problem is diferent then this question, yes you should, I was trying to create a chat with you so we don't fill the comment, but was unable to create one.

Comment: @Camadas Yeah, It looks like the problem is with ID, always is set to 0. But thanks for your time

Comment: (new SqlParameter("@email", element.Email));      (1)  do a business logic check that is like "if element.Email.Length > ConstantEmailMaxLength" and fail the request "early".   (2)      you can hack it with (new SqlParameter("@email", element.Email.Substring(0, ConstantEmailMaxLength));   but that is a poor practice.      Most string columns has max-lengths.  Your business logic should match.